# Javascript code not working anymore when loaded on chrome extension

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome-extension

i am developing a chrome extension and i have a long code, but this small part of it doesn't work:

```
document.querySelector('a[data-style-name="Red"]').click()
```

let me explaining better, this part of the code **works only when i put it on the chrome console of the website**, but it doesn't work,  when i put it on the javiscript file with the other part of the code that is working fine, also it "stops" the other part of the code, nothing works anymore...

can someone please tell me what i am doing wrong and how to  fix it?

Comment: This element is added by the page script later, after your content script has run. You can wait for the element using setTimeout or MutationObserver.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
document.querySelector('a[data-style-name="Red"]').onclick = () => alert("It's ok!");
```

```js
document.querySelector('a[data-style-name="Red"]').onclick = () => alert("It's ok!");
```

```html
<a data-style-name="Blue">Blue</a>
<a data-style-name="White">White</a>
<a data-style-name="Red">Red</a>
```

Comment: no, it doesn't work.. and it doesn't give any alert